# Theoretical Timing possible? (not changes for each evaluation)

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, evaluation, built-in-symbols

Is there a method to measure **theoretic time load** (hope +theoretic memory load) of an evaluation?

They should not change - **always generate same value after pressing Enter key**(=evaluation).

Hope they are even same in different environment(=different computers).

For example

```
Timing[1000000!;]
```

gives sometimes `0.125`, sometimes `0.140625`, sometimes `0.15625`.

I want an imaginary function `TheoreticTiming`

```
TheoreticTiming[1000000!;]
```

which outputs always `0.125`

There are built-in function `AbsoluteTiming` but it also changes for each evaluation, just like `Timing`.

Comment: No, not possible. Also (as suggested in one response) not what you want. You are looking for a way to gauge algorithm/implementation complexity, as measured in some basic set of units such as machine integer or double precision operations. That's something one would need to code on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica runs on general-purpose operating systems (Windows/Linux/MacOS). On such systems, a multitude of services (daemons) are constantly running in the background. These services load the system differently at different times. The OS alone determines when programs get access to the requested resource (CPU, Memory, Disk, Network etc).

A CPU is a resource. You may run multiple kernels through Mathematica, but access to the CPU core(s) is granted by the OS depending on other tasks awaiting execution in the queue. The answer to your question is "No" as it is not the design goal of a general purpose OS to provide the same (or pre-determined) execution trajectory (resource assignment) to any program or service on first/successive runs (let alone a calculation).

---

(Not relevant to the question but) On the CPU level itself, the instruction pipelines are not deterministically enqueued meaning that the CPU prefetches instructions based on a heuristic algorithm. You can look up "branch predictor". Furthermore, the CPU may or may  not execute instructions in the same order as submitted (lookup "Out of Order Execution"). Add to all this a cache scheduling algorithm trying to minimize memory access.

---

There is a hint of an xy-problem in your question. If you want guaranteed execution time for a real-time application, you will have to resort to other (more deterministic) platforms.

Answer (score 4):

For the sort of computer that you need for *Mathematica*, it is not possible. Modern high-speed processors use all kinds of shortcuts to speed execution, and these shortcuts depend on the history of everything that has gone on in the computer in its recent execution trajectory, not just *Mathematica*. A simple microcontroller running a single program can have predictable timing, but the computer you use for *Mathematica* cannot.